# About EJB Beans Constructs and Java Servlet Inits

Tags: java, eclipse, servlets, ejb-3.0

I have created a SimpleBean.java

```
public class SimpleBean implements SimpleBeanRemote  
{  
    private static String str = "Test";  

    private int value =0;  

    public SimpleBean()  
    {  
        G += " A";  
    value++;  
    }   

    public String getValue()
    {  
        return G + Integer.toString(value);  
    }  
}
```

In the servlet, I have declared an `private @EJB SimpleBeanRemote` bean. In the `doGet` handler, `bean.getValue()` statement is called.
The return outcome: Test A A1
It seems that the `SimpleBean` is constructed by twice. For my observation, Once is in the EJB construction and another issued by the Servlet for @EJB bean. I want to ask is it correct for the initialization of the EJB. If the SimpleBean is created twice, then the first one is no use?

Is It possible for constructing the EJB object for one-time only.

Would we share and discuss these operations mean?

Answer (score 0):

To understand that, you should take a look at the [types of session beans](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gipjg.html#gipkr).

And, if you are sure you need this:

> constructing the EJB object for one-time only.

, you should go for a singleton session bean (using the JavaEE 6 [@Singleton](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/ejb/Singleton.html) annotation).

Comment: Of course this only work if the user can use ejb-3.1. But good to mention it as option.